# Excecute command in vSphere Guest machine with Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, windows-server-2012-r2, vsphere, pyvmomi

I am trying to change the IP of a Windows Server 2012R2 vmware guest machine with the [vmware_vm_shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vmware_vm_shell_module.html) module. So far I have been able to clone the VM from a template with the [vsphere_guest](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html) module without problems, but when I try the following task to change the IP:

```
- name: Configure IP address
  local_action:
    module: vmware_vm_shell
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    cluster: "{{ Cluster }}"
    vm_id: "{{ machine }}"
    vm_username: "{{ machineUser }}"
    vm_password: "{{ ansible_windows_password  }}"
    vm_shell: "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowershell\\1.0\\powershell.exe"
    vm_shell_args: " -command (Get-NetAdapter -Name Ethernet |New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress {{ new_machine_ip }} -PrefixLength {{ new_machine_mask_bits }} -DefaultGateway {{ new_machine_gateway }} )-and (Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -ServerAddresses {{ new_machine_dns }})"
    vm_shell_cwd: "C:\\Windows\\Temp"
    validate_certs: False
```

The response from Ansible is `"msg": "File <unspecified filename> was not found"`.

I get the same error when I try to run the `execute_program_in_vm.py` script from [pyvmomi-community-samples](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/execute_program_in_vm.py): `Caught vmodl fault : File <unspecified filename> was not found`

The vmware user I have has all the `Guest Operations` permissions set. What am I missing here?

PS: I followed [this guide](http://devopspecialist.co.uk/2016/08/04/ansible-tower-and-vsphere-talking-to-a-windows-server-2012-with-no-ip-address/).

Comment: My version of VMware vCenter server is 5.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try it again with this task I made. This module has sometimes problems with parsing powershell commands. At least that's the experience I had. I don't know exactly why my command is working and yours is not.
I replaced the command in "vm_shell_args".

You just have to replace the values in the square brackets.

**Edit:**
Also try the playbook again but with the variables written without the spaces (e.g. `"{{vcenter_hostname}}"` instead of `"{{ vcenter_hostname }}"`

```
  - name: change IP
    local_action:
      module: vmware_vm_shell
      hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
      password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
      cluster: "{{ Cluster }}"
      vm_id: "{{ machine }}"
      vm_username: "{{ machineUser }}"
      vm_password: "{{ ansible_windows_password  }}"
      vm_shell: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\1.0\powershell.exe'
      vm_shell_args: 'netsh interface ip set address [Interface name] static [New IP] [Subnetmask] [Gateway]'
```

Comment: Got the same error, `"msg": "File <unspecified filename> was not found"` When using the following lines: 
`vm_shell: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\1.0\powershell.exe'`

`vm_shell_args: 'netsh interface ip set address Ethernet static 10.0.110.42 255.255.255.0 10.0.110.1`

Do you have some more tricks I can try?

Comment: Can you give me the whole message you get when running the playbook?
And have you forgot to place the apostrophe ( ' ) at the end of `vm_shell_args: 'netsh interface ip set address Ethernet static 10.0.110.42 255.255.255.0 10.0.110.1` ?

Comment: Here is the complete output I get (I have also removed the spaces as you updated with:) http://pastie.org/10987987

Comment: Seems like a unusual output for me. On which OS do you run this playbook? And how do you run the playbook: do you use the command ansible-playbook? And which versions of Ansible, Python and Pyvmomi are you using?

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 with the ansible-playbook command. Versions: Ansible 2.2.0.0, python 2.7.6, pyvmomi 6.5 and
pywinrm 0.2.2